# How to make AJAX content load smoothly while sliding Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble getting my div to slide smoothly upon the "View Activity" text being clicked. What I wish to achieve is this:

- When the "View Activity" link is clicked, I want the div to slide open smoothly
- Once full open, the div should display "Loading..." until the content is fully loaded
- Once the content is fully loaded, it should replace the "Loading..." text inside the div

What really happens

- When the "View Activity" link is clicked, the div suddenly opens and then instantly closes
- If I click the link once more it slides open normally and slides closed smoothly when clicked again

How do I make it slide open smoothly the first time and load the content smoothly while this happens? I suspect this has something to do with the content of div being changed while sliding, but I have no idea how to fix it.

***HTML***

```
<div class="listing_activity_container">
   <span style="cursor: pointer;" class="listing_activity_link <?php echo $listing->listing_id ?>">View Activity</span>
   <div class="activityContent_<?php echo $listing->listing_id ?>"></div>
</div>
```

***JQUERY***

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".listing_activity_link").click(function()   {
            var listing_id = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]
            var url = "<?php echo site_url('AJAX/ajax_default/listing_activity_seller'); ?>";

            $(".activityContent_"+listing_id).slideToggle();
            $(".activityContent_"+listing_id).html('Loading...');
            $.post(url, {listing_id: listing_id} ,function(data) {
               $(".activityContent_"+listing_id).html(data);
            });
       });   
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `animate` and register a [complete callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$(".activityContent_"+listing_id).animate({"height":100}, { complete: function(){
    $(".activityContent_"+listing_id).html('Loading...');
    ...
}});
```

This code will be executed after the animation has finished.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to make the div slide out to accommodate the true height of the resulting content?

Comment: Try to load the content into an invisible div. Then use that height to slide the div (you might be able to slide the visible div slowly and set the anim target when the content has loaded, so there is no waiting time for the user). When the anim is over, swap the two divs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think slideToggle is the function your looking for...

If you want to open the div to a set height I would use

```
$(".activityContent_"+listing_id).animate({"height":100});
```

And add some detection so it doesn't try to load the ajax when you're closing the div